# Force calculation to jump

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

I was trying to calculate the force required for a person to jump. Initially, it looks a very easy question, but it quickly became tough as I worked on it.

First of all, let us assume that person or his/her center of mass rises $h$ meters from the ground. Let us take force acted by legs as $F$. However, I run into confusion. Initially, $F$ is acting along with $mg$. However after jumping, a person is technically in free fall, so only gravity will act, and the motion can be predicted.

I figured out that I need time until which force is acting, which however is difficult to calculate in real life and may be unreliable/inaccurate.

I wish to calculate $F$ without the time variable, and solely on the height attained and weight of the person. Is it possible or is a time variable required, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that the centre of mass is at an initial height H and that the jump takes it to a height h, you can calculate the initial velocity needed, which turns out to be:

$$v_0 = \sqrt{2g \left(h - H \right)}.$$

(This is easily done taking into account these equations: $0 = v_0 - gt$ and $h = H + v_0 t - 1/2 g t^2$).

But now, if we want the force that achieves that initial velocity, we need the time. This is called the impulse, which is usually an integral and is measured in $Ns$. We can assume (but I think is not true for a real person jump) that we apply a constant force in a period $t$. Then:

$$v_0 = a_0 t \Rightarrow F = m a_0 = \frac{m v_0}{t}.$$

But, as I said, the real force is not constant in a real human jump, so this is an approximation, I guess. For instance, if the initial velocity needs to be $5m/s$, the mass is $50 kg$ and the force is applied for $0.1 s$, then it would be $F = 2500N$.

Again, this is an approximation. This would be more accurate if applied to an elastic ball that is pressed to the ground and allowed to bounce afterwards.